# Who tells us that the whole Bible is inspired?

Tags: bible, inspiration

I understand the inspiration concept, but I don't understand how to consider a quote if it's inspired from God [then we consider it God's Words],  or if it explanations by the the apostle or prophet?

Is there any verse in the Bible says that the whole Bible is inspired, and not absolute-human-talk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Bible does say that all the scriptures are inspired, which means "God-breathed":

> All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness. (2 Timothy 3:16, NIV)

Though human writers did produce the scriptures, the ultimate source of the scriptures is God himself. When others spoke the scriptures they did so through God's breath.

In its original context this verse really refers only to the Old Testament. Peter however refers to Paul's letters as scripture, showing that the Apostles recognised that they were writing new inspired scriptures:

> And remember, our Lord’s patience gives people time to be saved. This is what our beloved brother Paul also wrote to you with the wisdom God gave him— speaking of these things in all of his letters. Some of his comments are hard to understand, and those who are ignorant and unstable have twisted his letters to mean something quite different, *just as they do with other parts of Scripture*. And this will result in their destruction. (2 Peter 3:15-16, NLT)

Comment: Interesting how many notable and memorable 3:16 verses there are!

Comment: [Austin 3:16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Cold_Steve_Austin#Austin_3:16_-_The_rise_of_Stone_Cold_.281996.E2.80.931997.29) also.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, as a matter of fact, one of the "father" of Computer Science, Donald E. Knuth did a research on how profound 3:16 is through out the Bible and he wrote a book about it: http://www.amazon.com/3-16-Bible-Texts-Illuminated/dp/0895792524

Answer (score 1):

There are a combination of factors involved in determining whether the whole of The Bible (the Hebrew scriptures plus the Christian Greek scriptures) can be believed as inspired of God. If God has inspired all of the various writings that make up what later came to be called The Bible, then we can confidently quote it as the word of God, and not just the word of men.

This means that if we just quote bits from the Bible that claim those words are inspired of God, that - in itself - will not constitute sufficient evidence. Ideally, we should find so much evidence of the authenticity of what the Bible says (internally and externally), we could point to that as proof sufficient. Then we would not be relying on what this man, or that man, or another woman says.

This is a problem with various writings. There are other scriptures apart from The Bible, whose proponents say things such as, The Book of Mormon says in its last book called Moroni, ch.10 vss.3-5, that God bears witness of the truthfulness of the Book of Mormon to all who ask Him in faith. I've got a copy of the Book of Moron here, and the charge is made that if you are sincere in asking, with faith in Christ, then the Holy Spirit will let you know the truth of all things contained in the Book of Mormon.

Now, being a Christian for over five decades, and having been brought up on the Bible for nearly two decades prior to then, I immediately recognized those verses as being 'lifted' in large part from the far more ancient Bible, and I found very many other similar examples, all written in the King James style of writing. But here's the rub: those who uphold the Book of Mormon as fitting the bill as inspired of God because it says so, deny the same truth applies equally to the far older Bible that originally made such claims. They say the Bible is only accurate and inspired of God in so far as it has not been corrupted, Joseph Smith's annotated version of The Bible being what they go by. I mention this because wherever people disagree with bits in the Bible, they try to direct one to their own leaders' writings, saying these 'explain' the Bible properly. The question here is that ***who*** tells us something is inspired of God - or not - need not prove anything. We may be no further forward if we go by what other people say.

Anyone wanting to know if the whole Bible is inspired needs to start reading it prayerfully for themselves. And, given that Jesus Christ said no-one can come to God the Father except through him (John 14:6), and that only God the Father draws people to Christ (John 6:44 & 65), what the Bible says about the Father and the Son is the only authoritative source. Going anywhere else for information (either other literature, or to other people) could lead one astray. If the whole Bible is the inspired word of God, and God cannot lie (Romans 3:4), then ***it*** will lead us to the Christ of the Bible, and God the Father. There's no short-cut. Start reading in order to discover the Father and the Son (the gospel accounts are ideal for that) and then you can make your own mind up once the Holy Spirit who inspired it brings you to spiritual life.

Answer (score 0):

If the Bible was not inspired by God, other races would have written similar stories about encounters they supposedly had with supernatural or divine beings. The Romans, The Greeks, The Persians, The Babylonians, The Egyptians and others. But none of these tribes, not even Americans who are so advanced that it is on record that their men walked on the moon have a narrative that explains the beginning to the end.

The only way Moses would have known names of men who existed before and after the flood is because God himself told him about it. This is self explanatory, you have to believe that God himself authorised every single iota in it.

Is there any other tribe on earth that has a written record of a genealogy from the first man till the time of Christ? The simple answer is no and that's why the Bible is God inspired because only God would know of who gave birth to who even when man had not yet figured out how to write.

Answer (score -2):

The word "scripture" simply means "writings" or "that which is written".
It is obviously not true that everything that is written is true.

The Inspired Translation of 2 Timothy 3:16 reads:
"And *all scripture given by inspiration of God*, is profitable..."
([2 Timothy 3:16, see footnote a](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/2-tim/3?lang=eng&id=16-17#p16)).
This is a crucial contextual qualification.

The Inspired Translation of 2 Peter 1:20 corrects to "no prophecy of the scriptures is given of any private will of man", making it comport with verse 21 in the same chapter: "For the prophecy came not in old time by the will of man: but holy men of God spake as they were moved by the Holy Ghost"
([2 Peter 1:20, see footnote a](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/2-pet/1?lang=eng&id=20#p20)).

There is no Scripture stating that the entirety of "the Bible" as such is inspired. Those stating otherwise are begging the question of what the Bible is, which is a collection of texts compiledmany years after the last inspired contents of the Bible were originally written.
The only way to discern which passages and words were given by inspiration of God is to have the inspiration of God in the present, necessitating a modern prophet and seer called of God to clarify the distinctions and enhance our understandings, settling contentions by the pure word of God.

God did this in 1820 when He called Joseph Smith, a farm boy 14 years of age, to  be the first prophet in the last days. His work included restoring many passages of the Bible to their original and untampered state.
You can read the account of his calling here:

[Joseph Smith -- History](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/pgp/js-h/1?lang=eng)

Comment: **For Clarification** The "farm boy" of New York in the 1820s was not THE prophet for the end-times!  There have been many prophets with better credentials (accurate prophecies). It is incredulous that that boy raised without any knowledge of Greek and Hebrew syntax would be qualified to discern or determine what is correctly translated and inspired and what is not. The part of the Mormon Bible that exists contains error; for example the pages with the Egyptian hieroglyphics mislabeled  and doctored up by Joeseph!

Comment: @raygrant He is the prophet of the Restoration of the Gospel of Jesus Christ.
Joseph Smith's prophecies have been accurate to a tee, as has those of his successors. No one else's have come close.
No one has accounted for the existence of the Book of Mormon without admitting that it is of God, and no one ever will.
The evidences for this are abundant, but all people are free to place themselves eternally where they are most comfortable, and God will force no one to enjoy His presence and blessings eternally.