# Who or what established the divine inspiration for the authors of the bible?

Tags: life-of-jesus, bible, canon, scriptures, inspiration

Conventional Christianity would assert that all authors of the bible were divinely inspired to write exactly what they wrote.

What evidence is used as the basis of this assertion?

Is there recorded evidence of God establishing this through supernatural revelation, inferential or explicit evidence from some of the early writers (Clement, Polycarp, Irenaeus, etc.), or something else altogether?

Comment: Jack, please consider adding references to your assertions that they are just peoples' opinions and that they should be considered God's word.  Also, you may want to consider referencing the denomination which you would like to hear from.  LASTLY, since we're talking about the OT and Psalmists, you may want to ask this on Judaism.SE

Comment: Related: [Who tells us that the whole Bible is inspired?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/who-tells-us-that-the-whole-bible-is-inspired) [Are Paul's letters to be taken as God's word?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6627/are-pauls-letters-to-be-taken-as-gods-word) [What was Jesus' view on the authority of scripture?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/what-was-jesus-view-on-the-authority-of-scripture)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: The problem with every revealed religion. You believe that the prophet spoke to God. You believe the prophet first, then God. I think this falls more under a general philosophy question, which makes it off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 4):

For most Christian denominations, the answer is simple. [Scripture is supernaturally inspired.  The people who wrote the Bible wrote exactly what God intended them to write](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/from-a-fundamentalist-standpoint-what-does-the-phrase-inspired-infallible-in).

See [the CARM article on 2 Timothy 3:16](http://carm.org/christianity/sermons/2-timothy-316-all-scripture-inspired) for a more in-depth explanation.

Also [from the allaboutruth.org website](http://www.allabouttruth.org/all-scripture-is-inspired-of-god-and-beneficial-faq.htm):

> The Bible tells us that all Scripture is inspired of God and
>   beneficial. 2 Peter 1:20-21 says, "Above all, you must understand that
>   no prophecy of Scripture came about by the prophet's own
>   interpretation. For prophecy never had its origin in the will of man,
>   but men spoke from God as they were carried along by the Holy Spirit."
>
> 1 Corinthians 2:13 states, "This is what we speak, not in words taught
>   us by human wisdom but in words taught by the Spirit, expressing
>   spiritual truths in spiritual words." God impressed man with His
>   message, then the individual author, using his own style of expression
>   based on his personal, educational, and cultural resources put the
>   message into words.
>
> Romans 10:8 phrased it this way: "...The word is near you; it is in
>   your mouth and in your heart. . ." God communicated to the author the
>   content that He wanted written, and the author phrased the content
>   with his skill, style, mind, and language. We can be certain that,
>   although the very words came from each author, the message was as God
>   had intended and is authentic, reliable, and infallible. - [See more here](http://www.allabouttruth.org/all-scripture-is-inspired-of-god-and-beneficial-faq.htm#sthash.7OHdLSgk.dpuf)

Comment: Is there any notable evidence from sources other than the authors themselves, as is the case in the passages in your answer. Also, what would be the presumed definition of 'scripture'? Is this a commonly understood definition throughout the bible and early Christianity? If so, is it defined as the 66 books in the mainstream Christian Canon?

Answer (score 0):

I could give you a long drawn out answer to your question, citing all kinds of Scripture, but the true question here is why would you believe what I say over the words of Jesus himself?

> Luke 4:4 (many Translations)  But Jesus answered him, saying, "It is written, 'MAN SHALL NOT LIVE BY BREAD ALONE, BUT BY EVERY WORD OF GOD.' "

Comment: Who gets to decide what constitutes the "word of God"? The Church Fathers? They burnt the Gnostics at the stake for having their own views about what constitutes the "word of God". Did Jesus whisper in the ears of the Church Fathers what is the "word of God"? Bad answer.

Comment: @gideonmarx Perhaps you might need to do a little research on that.Jesus was quoting Moses from Deuteronomy 8:3  So He humbled you, allowed you to hunger, and fed you with manna which you did not know nor did your fathers know, that He might make you know that man shall not live by bread alone; but man lives by every word that proceeds from the mouth of the LORD. and in doing so Jesus who is God was validating the Old Testament. If you care to do a little studying you will find that Jesus validated a lot of Scripture.

Comment: So, exactly how does your answer explain the validity of the letters of Paul? You completely missed the question. Bad, bad answer.

Comment: @gideonmarx We do not need to argue here, but sometimes it is better to do some research on your own before you ask a question. I could do the research for you and continue to post answers in comments until we are both blue in the face, but arguing back and forth here makes little sense. If you do not find an acceptable answer to your question I will be happy to help you in your research. But let's not be testy with one another as it is not how Jesus taught us to receive one another.

Comment: David Stratton answered the question properly and me agreeing with him or not is unimportant, he gets +1. You posted a 'comment' as an 'answer', and then have the nerve to defend your position by insulting me. Back down!